# Raw Data Transformation

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm having data like

| columnname | value | table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | X |
| b | 2 | X |
| a | 3 | X |
| b | 4 | X |
| a | 5 | X |
| b | 6 | X |

and need to transform into

| table | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 |
| X | 3 | 4 |
| X | 5 | 6 |

Comment: Please don't post images, and at the very least show us what you tried yourself, and why it does not produce the expected results.

Comment: I'm doing it in python and tried pivot and groupby but didn't work

Comment: please post what you've tried. it should be doable with a pyspark `pivot`

Answer (score 1):

```
select tbl
      ,a
      ,b
from
(
select *, (row_number() over(order by value)-1)/2 as rn
from   t
) t 
pivot(max(value) for columnname in(a, b)) p
```

| tbl | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 2 |
| X | 3 | 4 |
| X | 5 | 6 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VYfLI8rJ)

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got below results:**

> **Please follow below code:**

I created sample data frame as per above requirement:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(
    [
        ("a",1,"X"), ("b",2,"X"), ("a",3,"X"),("b",4,"X"),("a",5,"X"),("b",6,"X")
    ]
)
df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["columnname","value","table"])    
df_data.show()
```

[image]

Then, I Converted the spark Dataframe to pandas Dataframe using `toPandas()` and I tried with **pivot**  and **groupby** functions to rotate data from one column to multiple columns and also it will transform rows to columns.

> **Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

#converted dataframe to pandas
pdf = df_data.to_pandas_on_spark()
req=[]
for i in range(1,(len(pdf)//2+1)):
    req.extend([i,i])
print(req)

pdf['counter']=req
print(pdf)

df1 = pdf.to_spark()
df1.show()
    
# From above dataframe to get the maximum values I am using group by counter,pivot by columnname. max by value with columns

df1.groupby('counter').pivot('columnname').max('value').withColumn('table',lit('x')).select('table','a','b').show()
```

**Running above code. I got this output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: how can we implement this if we don't know about the columnname values. we are receiving dynamic values (no fixed columnnames as  'a' and 'b')?

Comment: hi @Arun, if you have dynamic values then don't select fixed columnnames

Comment: you will get output without select column names also just remove `select('table','a','b')` from above code.